# android - trying to authorize a user for vk.com

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, android-webview

I'm trying to authorize a vk.com user (OAuth 2.0) as described [here](http://vk.com/developers.php?id=-1_37230422&s=1) and [here](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-17680044&p=OAuth_Authorization_Dialog). The problem: each time I see just a blank screen, nothing seems to happen except of single call to GC. I tested my WebView, it displays any addresses starting with *https* without any problems. I guess my URL is invalid but I also don't see any error messages, it looks like the WebView just do not display the authorization dialog. I'm not familiar with OAuth system, any help is greatly appreciated. Code goes below

P.S. I use a bitmask 8 since I only need to access user's audio.

```
    private static final String ACCESS = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=123456&redirect_uri= https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html/&display=touch&response_type=token&scope=8";

         private WebViewClient mWebClient = new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    return false;
}
 @Override
 public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
     handler.proceed(); 
 }

     };
     web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
     web.setWebViewClient(mWebClient);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl(ACCESS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out. Posting as an answer since there may be developers interested in accessing vk.com. The correct authorization request from android devices looks like:

```
   private final String VK_AUTH = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=123456&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=8&display=touch&response_type=token ";
```